# React/Typescript: How do I pass and "type" props down through multiple components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, react-props

In my React/Typescript project, I have a challenge:

1. From the Child component I pass a prop `class` down:

   `Child class={{ myBanner: styles.myBanner } />`

   I typed `class` prop as follows:

   ```js
    import { SerializedStyles } from '@emotion/react';

    import { Class as MyCustomBannerClass } from './MyBanner/MyBanner.types';

    type Class = Partial<Record<'root', SerializedStyles>> & {
      myBanner: MyCustomBannerClass;
    };

    export type Props = {
      class: Class;
    };
   ```

   ---
2. Inside Child component I have `<MyBanner/>` component, where I also have a `class` prop:

   ```js
   export type Class = Partial<Record<'root', SerializedStyles>>;

   export type Props = {
     class?: Class;
   };

   <MyBanner class={props.class?.myBanner} />
   ```

This is all working fine.
Now from within **Parent** component, through **Child** and `<MyBanner/>`,
 I am able to override a css style in **Parent** from `<MyBanner />` component.

---

**The challenge:**

Now I have a case:

- Inside **Child**, I have another child `<AnotherChild/>`.
- And within `<AnotherChild />`, I have `<MyBanner/>` component.

**Question:**

How do I pass and type `class={{ myBanner: styles.myBanner }` through both...

1. **Child:**`<Child class={{ myBanner: styles.myBanner } />`
2. And **AnotherChild:** `<AnotherChild class={???} />`

...and pass it down to `<MyBanner class={props.class?.myBanner} />`?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem that can easily be solved by using `React.useContext`
 ...in other words, the ContextAPI. Here's the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) about it.

To tackle your issue specifically, you can `useContext` like this:
**Parent.tsx**

```js
/** PARENT **/

import React from 'react';
import { SerializedStyles } from '@emotion/react';
import { Class as MyCustomBannerClass } from './MyBanner/MyBanner.types';

// define parent context
type Class = Partial<Record<'root', SerializedStyles>> & {
  myBanner: MyCustomBannerClass;
};

interface Props {
  parentClass?: Class,
};

export const ParentContext = React.createContext({} as Props);

export const Parent = props => {
  const parentClass = React.useRef({ myBanner: styles.myBanner });

  const contextProps = {
    parentClass: ..., // add props to be passed down
  };

  return (
    // We pass (or literally provide) "parentClass" (and more) 
    // to all the children of "Parent"
    <ParentContext.Provider value={{ ...contextProps }}>
      <Child />
    </ParentContext.Provider>
  )
};
```

---

**Child.tsx**

```js
// FIRST-CHILD

import React from 'react';

// define context
type Class = Partial<Record<'root', SerializedStyles>>;

interface Props {
  childClass?: Class,
};

export const ChildContext = React.createContext({} as Props);

// define component
export const Child = props => {
  const childClass = React.useRef({ ... })

  const contextProps = {
    childClass: ..., // add props to be passed down
  };

  return (
    // Both "MyBanner" and "AnotherChild" are provided with both `class` props
    // from "Parent" and "Child" and it can go on and on...
    <ChildOneContext.Provider value={{ ...contextProps }}> 
      <MyBanner />
      <AnotherChild />
    </ChildOneContext.Provider>
  )
};
```

---

**AnotherChild.tsx** (You can do the same in "MyBanner")

```js
// SECOND-CHILD

import React from 'react';
import { ParentContext } from './Parent';
import { ChildContext } from './Child';

// define component
const AnotherChild = props => { 
  const { parentClass } = React.useContext(ParentContext);
  const { childClass } = React.useContext(ChildContext);

  return (
    <div className={ParentClass}>
      <div className={childClass}></div>
    </div>
  )
};
```

Note:
If you want a child component to override the `class` prop in any case, you can define the classes with `useState` instead of `useRef` as I've done in this case.

---

That said, at the back of your mind, remember that `ContextAPI` is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for a tree of React components, such as your case!